# Protractor - Test Suites - Not running in sequence

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am using Protractor + Jasmine.

I have a weird issue. 
I have 2 test suites (or Spec.js). I want to run them one after another (strictly). However, protractor is starting the Spec1 related BeforeAll(). And quickly jumping to Spec2 related BeforeAll().

In Spec1, there is one login function, and some times the login is taking 40 seconds. Is this is the reason?

And, after logged in from Spec1, Protractor jumps to Spec2 and starts executing "BeforeAll". And later comes back to Spec1 related "describe".

Please bear with me about these big files, as they are critical to debug.

If I run these two Specs separately, ie., not in a sequence, everything was fine.

Spec1.js

```
beforeAll(function () { 
    originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = globalconstants.wait10Mints;
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.get(env.appUrl);
    browser.getTitle().then(function (title) {
        expect(title, "Browser title is not the expected. But " + browser.getTitle()).toBe("Valueone");
    });
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
    loginPage.login();

    commonPage.navigateToUsers();
    usersPage.deleteUsers(name); 
});

describe('Create Users', function () {
it("Create user", function () {
something 
});

it("Create user", function () {
something 
});
});
```

Spec2.js

```
beforeAll(function () { 
    originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = globalconstants.wait10Mints;
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.get(env.appUrl);
    browser.getTitle().then(function (title) {
        expect(title, "Browser title is not the expected. But " + browser.getTitle()).toBe("Valueone");
    });
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
    loginPage.login();

    commonPage.navigateToAccounts();
    accountsPage.deleteAccounts(number); 
});

describe('Create Accounts', function () {
it("Create Savings", function () {
something 
});

it("Create current account", function () {
something 
});

});
```

Conf.js

```
var env = require('./Utils/env.js');
var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter-2');
var JasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

exports.config =
    {

        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9999',
        directConnect: true,
        framework: 'jasmine2',

        suites: {
            1sp: './mysuites/1Spec.js',
            2sp: './mySuites/2Spec.js',
        },

        capabilities: {
            'browserName': env.browserName,
            'platform': env.osName,

            //Closes any existing browsers
              'shardTestFiles': false,
              'maxInstances': 1
        },

        params: {
            tempVar: false
        },

        onPrepare: async () => {
            global.result = false;

            var fs = require('fs-extra');
            fs.emptyDir('./Reports/Screenshots/', function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
                specDone: function (result) {
                    if (result.status == 'failed') {
                        browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
                            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                                var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./Reports/Screenshots/' + env.browserName + '-' + result.fullName + '.png');
                                stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
                                stream.end();
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            var width = 1600;
            var height = 1200;
            browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);

            //Html reporter
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new JasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
                consolidateAll: true,
                savePath: './Reports',
                filePrefix: 'xmlresults'
            }));
        },

        onComplete: async () => {

            var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
            capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
                testConfig = {
                    reportTitle: 'UI Test Execution Report',
                    outputPath: './Reports',
                    outputFilename: 'UI Test Results',
                    screenshotPath: './screenshots',
                    testBrowser: 'FireFox',
                    modifiedSuiteName: false,
                    screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true,
                    testPlatform: env.osName
                };
                new HTMLReport().from('./Reports/xmlresults.xml', testConfig);
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you post the capabilities section of your conf also?

Comment: Your full conf.js file would be really helpful. That is likely where the issue is

Comment: Attached the config - Thanks in advance to spend time to help me out - These are lengthy files, however, they help us to debug the issue.

Comment: what command are you using to execute your code?

Comment: As we have not yet integrated to Jenkins, from VSCode IDE I am running - Could this be the cause ? If everything else looks fine, then problem is with vscode itself.  Protractor is running "Parallel". Just starts Spec1 BeforeAll, jumpts to 2nd spec - executing BeforeAll method.

Comment: What I mean is how are you triggering the multiple specs together and on their own? Are you using commands such as `protractor conf.js --suites` or `protractor conf.js --suite 1sp`?

Comment: From VSCode's Console -- from within the Project >> protractor  .\config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I was able to recreate your issue and it appears to be related to how Jasmine handles beforeAll hooks. There is a complete discussion available [here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/873) and [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/708) but basically (and surprisingly) it appears that anything in your test file not declared within a describe will be executed before **ANY** tests are executed, including **beforeAll hooks**. This is surprising to me as I am almost certain I've used beforeAlls outside describes before without issue but can't verify that right now.

However, if you declare your beforeAll hook within your describe it will be hoisted up and still execute before your tests exactly the same as you are currently expecting it to behave now.

Can you try moving your beforeAll blocks within your describes as below:

**Spec1.js**

```
describe('Create Accounts', function () {
   beforeAll(function () { 
       originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
       jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = globalconstants.wait10Mints;
       browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
       browser.get(env.appUrl);
       browser.getTitle().then(function (title) {
           expect(title, "Browser title is not the expected. But " + browser.getTitle()).toBe("Valueone");
       });
       browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
       loginPage.login();

       commonPage.navigateToAccounts();
       accountsPage.deleteAccounts(number); 
   });

   it("Create Savings", function () {
       something 
   });

   it("Create current account", function () {
      something 
   });

});
```

**Spec2.js**

```
describe('Create Users', function () {
    beforeAll(function () {
        originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = globalconstants.wait10Mints;
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        browser.get(env.appUrl);
        browser.getTitle().then(function (title) {
            expect(title, "Browser title is not the expected. But " + browser.getTitle()).toBe("Valueone");
        });
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
        loginPage.login();

        commonPage.navigateToUsers();
        usersPage.deleteUsers(name);
    });

    it("Create user", function () {
        something
    });

    it("Create user", function () {
        something
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (again - as usual) DublinDev, for spending personal time to help me out! It is working perfectly  now (as I expected it to be). This almost took me 5-6 hours to figure out what went wrong - Still I could not understand. And thanks a ton! Am I doing my project, or you are doing it on my behalf! LOL

Comment: Haha no problem man! I am actually trying to improve my own knowledge of Protractor by reading questions here and trying to recreate/resolve them when I have some time so it's just a coincidence we keep bumping into each other :) This problem was interesting to me also as it seems very counter-intuitive so was very glad to help/learn!

Comment: @user3055964 I was thinking on this again and feel that this should remain the accepted answer as it did solve your issue and explains why it will be helpful for future users. If you disagree I can edit it to clean it up a little

Comment: It indeed an answer, it solved my issue, not sure what happened, but I previously flagged it as Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below one in your `config`.

`specs: ['src/**/*spec.js'], // This should be the relative path to you spec.js`

Now the test runs based on the file order in you path.

To run test: `protractor config.js`

`Suites` in your config is used to group your test based on functionality or something else.

The best way to solve the issue is to Move all your test in one file and have two `describe` in your spec.

**structure:**
**spec.js**

```
`describe()`
{
beforeall() \\ Spec1.js
it()
it()
}
describe(){
beforeAll()\\spec2.js
it()
it()
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks Madhan for your help! However, changing suites into specs did not help.  Protractor starts executing the first Spec BeforeAll, even before finishing that, it starts executing the second Spec BeforeAll.  Seems, "Parallel execution" is happening. I messed up something.

Comment: Share the config file with the changes i suggested will check that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Madhan to try to help me out - As you can see, DublinDev provided the solution.

Comment: The solution was the same spec structure in the answer provided. You can see that i have moved the `beforeAll()` in side the `describe`. You can upvote if the solution helped you.

Comment: Yes, I missed that out completely - Upvoted as this solves - However, the best way is not to move everything into a single file - That is not a robust/expandable framework then. Every functionality should exist in its own Spec -  Thanks!

Comment: @user3055964 This answer is certainly worth up voting as it does explain where your config could be optimized but I would disagree with it being the accepted answer due to it recommending fundamentally changing the structure of your tests which is not required to resolve your original issue. If another user finds this question at a later date it may not be clear why this solution resolves the issue

Comment: @DublinDev - I agree with your disagreement. The solution was partially correct and flawed. Anyway, I added my comments in the form of reply. I have taken back the 'accepted as answer' - So I have corrected my mistake.

Comment: @user3055964 No matter who answered it. The moto is get solution for the problem. Mark the answer which helped you to resolve the same.So that it helps someone who face the same problem

Comment: @Madhan - I agreed and upvoted as your answer helped me! However, that is not the correct approach, as it makes the framework as non-scalable and hard-to-maintain.